# In Wordpress I am trying to place a search bar in the middle of the front page. Not sure how

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Okay so I am pretty sure me attempting to place a search bar in the middle of my home page on my website does not depend on the theme itself. However, I have already tried to place a search bar there with the current theme and all it allows me to do it place one in the footer or header of certain pages.

Thank you for taking the time to help.

Comment: We need some code, what have you tried? what are you using?

Comment: Wordpress allows the user to enable a search bar in certain areas with no real coding at all. Not sure whether or not I need to customize the code itself instead of just enabling it on the Wordpress theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to remove `<?php get_search_form(); ?>` from your theme's sidebar template and place it in another template file (e.g. page.php) or in a custom page template.

If you put it in page.php be warned that it will show up in every page. You can make a [custom template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates) to avoid this and keep it on which ever page you designate.